# GIT setting binary filetypes in config?

Tags: git

I know that I can set up a .gitattributes for each project that I have in GIT, but I work with a lot of projects and they all have the same types of binary files. Is there anyway I can just set these filetypes in my git config and not have to worry about doing it for each project? That would be very useful.

Note that I am working on a small private development team, so we would all have the same git setup on our computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `core.attributesfile` in the global config to point to the gitattributes file that you want to affect all the repositories:

> core.attributesfile
>
> In addition to .gitattributes (per-directory) and .git/info/attributes, git looks into this file for attributes (see gitattributes(5)). Path expansions are made the same way as for
>   core.excludesfile.

For all users:

> Attributes for all users on a system should be placed in the
>   $(prefix)/etc/gitattributes file.